# New policies for desktop web games off of Facebook.com

Tags: facebook, web, desktop, policies

what is intended for "desktop web game off facebook.com" ?

How can I create a web game only on facebook.com ?

I currently have the game www.logogame.biz and I don't want to be impacted by the upcoming new policies.

I'd like to move the game "on facebook.com" to avoid the new restrictions. How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, maybe you skip the "Website with Facebook Login" part in developer settings and only provide your game directly via canvas. (eg. apps.facebook.com/logogame). that's what "on facebook.com" is all about, i guess.

Comment: That's exactly what I did! Thanks!